# emacs with sml-mode

Tags: emacs, sml, smlnj

I'm using sml-mode (Stefan Monnier) with emacs. The compiler is smlnj, on a laptop. However, when invoking the SML compiler, that splits the emacs frame into two windows, each fits 12 lines. How can I have the SML program editing buffer in its own emacs frame, and the SML-Inferior-Mode buffer on a separate emacs frame? Thank you.

Comment: You're probably using "window" and "frame" in the opposite meaning to their normal usage in Emacs lingo: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I've made the swap.

Comment: His name is Stefan Monnier, and he is the leader of the management of emacs for a few years.

Answer (score 3):

It was really straight!

First, invoke the SML compiler: `C-c C-b`
it asks for the default SML System: SMLNJ, MosML, etc.
type the name of the compiler to invoke, or press RETURN key to accept the default, if any.

Then, have the compiler window to display on its own frame, `C-x 5 2`

To kill (delete) the compiler window from within the SML program editing window, visit that window (either `C-x o` (letter o)) or by mouse. Then press `C-x 0` (zero).